# Como passar o valor de uma variável através de um botão para outra classe em Swift

Tags: ios, swift, classes, parâmetros

Tenho uma tela de login, com os campos e-mail e senha. Preciso utilizar em outra viewController o e-mail que foi utilizado para fazer login no sistema. Mas não consigo passar o e-mail digitado no viewController Login para outra viewController.

Comment: Você está usando storyboard? Se sim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577484/passing-variables-between-view-controllers

Comment: Use o método PrepareForSegue

Answer (score 2):

Se você está usando *Segues*, basta sobrescrever o método *prepareForSegue* na sua *ViewController* de login.

Por exemplo, supondo que a próxima *ViewController* se chame **NextViewController** e o ID da sua Segue seja **GoToNextSegue**, o código ficaria assim:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "GoToNextSegue" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! NextViewController
        vc.email = "aqui você informa o e-mail"
    }
}
```

Obviamente, na sua classe **NextViewController** você precisa ter um parâmetro chamado **email** que irá receber a informação.

Answer (score 1):

Caso você não utilize segue, pode passar da seguinte forma

Primeiro na VC-B declare a variavel que vai receber o valor.

```
//VC-B 
class VC_B: UIViewController{
    var Valor:String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(Valor)
    }
}

//VC_A
class VC_A: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func AbrirVC_B(sender:UIButton){
       let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc:VC_B = story.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC_B") as! VC_B
        vc.Valor = "Novo Valor"
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```